# Stop access to postgresql 12 by using pg_hba configuration not working with REJECT

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to prevent access to postgresql server using a web user. The plan in the future is to reject the IP subnet but for now I am trying to test with just my local IP address.

I am trying to reject my IP address in the pg_hba configuration but even after applying the change and reloading the pg_hba configuration I am still able to access why is this the case?
Below is the entry in pg_hba.conf -- note it is the first entry in the file also.

```
host  all web 172.10.252.65 255.255.255.255 reject
```

When I reload by running the below on the server itself

```
psql -c "SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Then try accessing the database server from my IP address using:

```
psql -h test-server -U web -d accounts
```

I can get in successfully....what am I doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The default for local connections with psql on *NIX OS is to connect via Unix-domain sockets. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.8)

> If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to `localhost` on machines that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

A `local` entry in `pg_hba.conf` catches connections via Unix-domain socket:

```
local  all web  reject
```

If you connect via local loopback your connection would originate from `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `::1/128` (IPv6). Use the host name `localhost` to cover both:

```
host  all web localhost reject
```

Must come before any other line that would allow the connection.

Find out how you actually connected by inspecting the [special variable `HOST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES):

```
test=> \echo :HOST
```

Returns `/var/run/postgresql` for the UNIX domain socket (`local`), or the host name / IP address actually in use.

[`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) provides more detailed information (incl. the effective client address, which is empty for connections via UNIX domain socket). After connecting to my local DB cluster via `localhost`, I get:

```
erwin=> SELECT pid, datname, usename, client_addr, client_hostname FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();
  pid  | datname | usename | client_addr | client_hostname 
-------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------------
 13084 | test    | erwin   | 127.0.0.1   | 
(1 row)
```

BTW, there are simpler ways to "reload" (send the Postgres server process a `SIGHUP` signal). [Basically:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html)

```
pg_ctl reload
```

On a Debian-based system, as unprivileged user, with multiple DB clusters installed:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 14 main reload
```

Comment: but if I am running psql does that connect via local? the concern I have is whether I impact anything else that would use the web user on local connection.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob: I added some more to clarify.

Comment: the issue I will have is I dont want to stop the user web altogther just either allow access via certain IPs or reject IPs. Think this will stop the web user altogether which is something I cannot do.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob Then allow those certain IPs first, and reject the rest in the next line with `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

> The plan in the future is to reject the IP subnet ...

Why do you feel the need to do this?

It suggests to me that your HBA access is set *too wide* to begin with.

I would recommend *only* allowing access from known, *trusted* machines (or subnets).

Comment: Hi @phill-w we have ascertained that employees are using a user which is designed for the applications only and they should not be using. Preventing the employee(s) subnet using the user would then mean they can/should request a user account. Not sure if this is the best approach but it allows us to then see what queries are coming from the apps vs employees terminals.

Comment: This is a *Data Breach*, and should be reported as such.  
Furthermore, the password used by this account must be changed immediately - /even if/ that means disrupting a Production system.  
These Users are almost certainly in breach of your company's Code of Conduct for computer use by acquiring access to computer resources to which they are not entitled.  They should be made aware of this in the clearest possible terms.